# Toggle different context menu based on v-for generated element clicked on

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have been struggling with this issue for hours now. I have a list of documents generated from via `v-for` based on `vuex` data. Where we have an array of documents. Each document is an object with data about that document AND an array of Views (Users who opened the document) with some basic data about each user.

```
"documents": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Doc 1",
            "date": "01.01.1995",
            "doc_website": "linktodocument1.com",
            "views": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "user_name": "Jon",
                    "doc_id": 1,
                    "view_date": "01.02.1996",
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "user_name": "Bob",
                    "doc_id": 1,
                    "view_date": "05.02.1996",
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Doc 2",
            "date": "01.01.2000",
            "doc_website": "linktodocument2.com",
            "views": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "user_name": "Bob",
                    "doc_id": 2,
                    "view_date": "01.02.1996",
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "user_name": "Jon",
                    "doc_id": 2,
                    "view_date": "05.02.1996",
                },
            ]
        },
]
```

I render the data with following:

```
<div
        v-for="document in documents"
        :key="document.id"
        class="flex flex-nowrap text-grey border-b-2 pt-8"
      >
        <div class="flex flex-1 items-center pl-4">
          <span class="material-icons text-3xl text-red">
            documentIcon
          </span>
          <a :href="document.doc_website" target="_blank"
            ><p class="pl-2">{{ document.name}}</p></a
          >
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-1 justify-center items-center">
          <p>
            Date: <strong>{{ document.date}}</strong>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-1 justify-end items-center pr-2 cursor-pointer">
          <!-- Start Tool -->
          <div @click="showViewsLog(document)">
            <p>
              Viewed by:
              <span v-for="view in document.views" :key="value.id"
                ><strong> {{ view.user_name }},</strong></span
              >
            </p>
            <div
              class="relative"
              v-bind:class="{
                hidden: !viewsMenuShow
              }"
            >
              <div
                class="z-10 w-52 absolute -left-24 lg:left-10 md:-left-10 shadow-lg bg-white border-2 border-grey rounded"
              >
                <div class="bg-teal text-center p-2">
                  <p class="text-sm font-bold text-white pb-1">
                    Views
                  </p>
                </div>
                <ul class="text-xs leading-4 text-grey py-3 pl-3 pr-3">
                  <li>
                    <div
                      v-for="(view, index) in document.views"
                      :key="view.id"
                      class="flex justify-between"
                    >
                      <div>{{ index + 1 }} - {{ view.user_name }} -</div>
                      <div>{{ view_date}}</div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- END Tooltip -->
        </div>
      </div>
```

The script to toggle the menu is

```
<script>
data() {
    return {
      viewMenu: false,
    };
  },
methods: {
showViewsLog(el) {
      this.viewMenu= !this.viewMenu;
    },
}
</script>
```

Please see image: for expected output.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nCiK.png

My question now... I want to be able to display a small popup above/below the 'viewed by' text with the whole list of views for that document. Currently when i click on the 'Viewed by' text the popup appears but it does so for BOTH records not just the one i clicked on. How do i do it so that only the clicked on text will show the menu and not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution has been provided on another forum so I'will post it here if anyone needes it.

All that needed doing was changing the `template` to

```
<div
  class="relative"
  v-bind:class="{
  hidden: viewsMenuShow !== document.id,
  }"
>
```

and the script:

```
data() {
    return {
      viewMenu: 0,
    };
  },
methods: {
     showViewsLog(el) {
       if (this.viewMenu=== el.id) {
        this.viewMenu= 0;
      } else {
        this.viewMenu= el.id;
      }
     },
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add document that you pass on click to data:

```
 <script>
   data() {
     return {
       viewMenu: 0
     };
   },
   methods: {
     showViewsLog(el) {
       if (this.viewMenu === el.id) {
         this.viewMenu = 0
       } else {
         this.viewMenu = el.id;
       }
     },
   }
 </script>
```

then i template add another condition:

```
:class="{
  hidden: !(document.id === viewMenu) || viewMenu === 0
 }"
```

and hidden class:

```
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Wow, it did something. Now the page loads with all of the menus open, clicking on one WILL close that menu but when clicking on another one the first one will comback and another click will remove the other one

Comment: Sorry mate, my bad, try now pls

Comment: This works for most part. The toggling works fine (i can open and close individual items) but their default state is to be visible. Meaning The page loads with all of them open and if i close one and try to close another again the first one will return

Comment: Ahh, then try to now, i changed answer

Comment: No luck my friend. the behaviour is the same as before. Closing indidual ones does work, but the page loads with all open, and closing one and trying to close another will firstly open previously closed and then will close the currently clicked on

Comment: But isn't that what you looking for "Meaning The page loads with all of them open and if i close one and try to close another again the first one will return"?

Comment: 1st. I really appriciate you taking time helping me with this.
2nd. No. i want the page to load with all of them closed, and clicking on one should open one and clicking on anohter should close the first and open the one clicked on